# Как найти min значение для каждого первого(x) и второго(y) числа в кортеже?

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Пример**

```
lis=[
    [(70, 70), (50, 350), (10, 50)],
    [(50, 350), (350, 350)],
    [(200, 450), (50, 0)]
]
x_min = 10
y_min = 0
```

Как я хотел это реализовать, но ответ не получается:

```
lis=[
    [(70, 0), (50, 350), (350, 50),(100, 50)],
    [(50, 350), (350, 350), (500, 350), (150, 350),],
    [(200, 450), (10, 100)]
]

x = min([row[0] for row in lis])
y = min([row[1] for row in lis])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас `lis` - не плоский список, а матрица (двумерный список). Если хотите найти `min` или `max` среди всех кортежей во всех строках необходимо сначала развернуть матрицу в плоский список:

```
import itertools
lis = list(itertools.chain(*lis))
x = min([row[0] for row in lis]) # 10
y = min([row[1] for row in lis]) # 0
```

Answer (score 1):

есть возможность еще аналогично через ключ:

```py
import itertools
print min(itertools.chain(*lis), key=lambda x: x[0])
print min(itertools.chain(*lis), key=lambda x: x[1])
```